# IE executes only last XHR request completely

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-10

my website loads additional stuff upon request via an XHR request. It works fine in Firefox but IE10 messes up. 
Basically, I loop over an array of 4 items representing 4 pages I might want to load. If the page does not exist the request is discarded.
The following code creates a title for each section. The section is taken from the loaded web page and padded to fit into the main page.

```
for (var i=0;i<titleArray.length;i++){

    var xhr_file = xhr_files.replace("xhr_replace",titleArray[i]);

    var sectTitle = document.createElement("P");
        sectTitle.setAttribute ("class","section_title");
        sectTitle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(titleArray[i]));

    if (IsDocumentAvailable(xhr_file)){
        //alert(xhr_file);
        newItem.appendChild(sectTitle);
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', xhr_file);
        client.send();  

        client.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (client.readyState == 4) {
                var FileTex = client.responseText;
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var FileHtml = parser.parseFromString(FileTex, "text/html");                        
                var FileCon = FileHtml.getElementsByTagName("DIV");

                for (var index = 0; index < FileCon.length; index++){
                    var tags = FileCon[index].cloneNode(true);                      
                    var images = tags.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

                    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                        var source = images[i].getAttributeNode("src").value;
                        var newSource = source.replace(/(\.\.\/)+/g,"");
                        images[i].setAttribute("src", newSource);
                    };
                    newItem.appendChild(tags);
                };                      
                newWrap.appendChild(newItem);
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Firefox creates nicely the titles and fills the section with the content of the web page. IE10 however seems to only load the last of the available items but creates titles for all existing web pages. In the network monitor of IE the XHR request is completed and the content is shown but not in the webpage. Oddly, when I uncomment the `alert(xhr_file);` everything is shown in IE10. So it seems that there is a timing error but I cannot figure out where. Synchronous request does not solve the problem.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. Your variables are being squashed in the next iteration. Don't use `alert()`, especially when testing async stuff. It blocks execution so your broken "async in a loop" appears to work.

Comment: One thing you can do is inside the `onreadystatechange` callback, change `client` to `this` so you're not relying on a variable whose value is being constantly updated before the responses come back.

Comment: ...that appears to be the only squashed variable that you're accessing from inside the callback, so it may fix it. That said, why not make a single request to fetch all the data at once instead of multiple requests? Probably more efficient that way.

Comment: To be clear, if the only variable you need is `client`, do *not* use the solution in the duplicate that @jfriend00 posted. That one makes a little more sense given that other question, but here it wouldn't at all. Even if you do need other variables, a better solution is to make a single request rather than multiple in a loop if at all possible.

Comment: @squint: changing `client` to `this` did not solve the problem but resulted in nothing happening at all. The request remains pending. To be clear: I tried `this.responseText` alone and together with `this.readyState` . So probably the answer in the duplicate question works but I do not understand the `(function(i){...})(i)` concept to implement it. Sadly, I went back to synchronous request which works. I think it is OK for a maximum of 4 requests. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Wait, you only changed `client` to `this` inside the callback, right? You still need it to be `client` outside the callback. The weird thing is that you have `newWrap` and `newItem` variables that are not present in your code, so I assumed them to be static. If they're not and are created inside the loop, then you'll need something like the other solution.

Comment: Yes, I only changed inside the callback. `newWrap` and `newItem` are static. But the `IsDocumentAvailable(xhr_file)` function tests the availability via a synchronous request anyway. So I got rid of this additional step and extract the data immediately, instead of opening another then asynchronous request. The amount of data is only a few 10Kbyte. But thanks for the effort and time.